# What is the best pattern for returning only required data in an object based on context?

Tags: class, design-patterns

I am going to ask this question by example. Say I am designing StackOverflow and I have all these posts that my users make. For every post, there are a large number of things that I track (title, tags, author, timestamps, comments, history, etc.).

So I design a class which is called Post that takes care of this.

When I hit the homepage of StackOverflow - I have to list a number of posts. Now I have a collection of posts structure (perhaps List).

The thing is that whenever I have to get a List, I don't need a lot of the details that are present in the Post itself. For instance, on the list page I don't need the history.

So, the question is, what is the best pattern for implementing something like this. Currently what we do is that we have a lighter version of the Post class (say PostLight) which is what is used in such scenarios - but this seems tacky.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to use [`LazyLoading`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) which does what you want and is commonly used with database queries.

Say you have a class `Post` which gets loaded from the database with only some *usual used* fields. Every other details get loaded only when the are requested.

Something like this could be used:

```java
public class Post
{
    private String title;
    private String text;
    private List<Post> history;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public List<Post> getHistory() {
        if (null == history) {
            history = loadHistory();
        }
        return history;
    }
}
```

So on a front page, where you list a couple of posts without details, the history would not be loaded.

You could inject a custom `DataLoader` at the time of instantiating a `Post` object and then call that loader at the time you *lazy load* additional data.

As an alternative you could also use the [`ProxyPattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) which gives you some similar behavior.

Comment: +1 I was about to suggest the same kind of self-filling intelligent object which fetches data on demand, but did not know it is called LazyLoading. So lets save it for later :)

Comment: Thanks. Here's the problem though (and my fault for not specifying it earlier) - where we are using this, our objects are being returned across a service boundary (more specifically, through an asp.net web api service).

I have looked at the possible use of DTOs to create various representations of the entity objects however I am not sure if that is the best idea (but might still be the only one).

Comment: @Vaibhav: DTOs are the right approach across service boundaries. Your domain layer (in the service back-end) can still implement lazy loading and the service layer can return different DTOs for different views of this domain object.

Comment: @Casablanca - yup, that is what I am leaning towards now. The only problem with DTOs is that you can really end up in a mess if you make too many.

In fact, we have also thought about not having DTOs and just not loading parts of the domain entity thinking that when it is serialized to JSON (this is what the asp.net web api will be doing) then it is almost auto creating appropriate DTOs since the JSON serializer will ignore the null fields in the domain entity objects when serializing.